# ASP update textbox after typing in it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I have a textbox on an asp page. This textbox gets filled with emails from a database, printing out one email per line in the textbox, each line seperated by a vbCrLf to make it work. The textbox is writable so that people can enter more emails or erase emails that are in that list. After changing the list of emails there is a save button that should read in the new list of emails and send them back.

However, after typing in a new email into the textbox or removing one from the textbox, I hit the save button and in the code behind it still reads the textbox's text as the original text without changes. I don't know why because the code only runs after I make the changes so when I call emailBox.Text (my textbox) it should look for whatever text is in the textbox, correct? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

VB:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try
            emailBox.Text = ""
            Dim tempstoreID As Integer = 101
            Dim ds As DataSet
            Dim emailList As String = ""
            ds = DBUtility.GetKisokAlertEmails(tempstoreID)
            If Not ds Is Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables.Count > 0 And ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For Each dr In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                    emailList = dr("EmailList")
                Next
            End If
            Dim seperatedEmailList() As String
            seperatedEmailList = Split(emailList, ";")
            For Each email As String In seperatedEmailList
                emailBox.Text &= email & vbCrLf
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim tempstoreID As Integer = 101
            LogUtility.LogMessage("Error in getting and parsing email list from database. " & ex.ToString, LogUtility.INFO_MESSAGE, tempstoreID)
        End Try
    End Sub

Protected Sub SaveButton(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim newEmailList() As String
        newEmailList = Split(emailBox.Text, vbCrLf)
        Dim regexExpression As New Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$")

        Dim valid As Boolean
        Dim errorEmail As String = "Nope"

        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        While counter < newEmailList.Length - 1
            If (regexExpression.IsMatch(newEmailList(counter))) Then
                valid = True
                counter += 1
            Else
                valid = False
                errorEmail = newEmailList(counter)
                Exit While
            End If

        End While

    End Sub
```

ASP:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="label1" Text="List Of Emails" runat="server" /> <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="emailBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Text="" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
            <br/><br/>
            <asp:Button Text="Save" OnClick="SaveButton" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button Text="Cancel" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="TestLabel" Text = "Hi" runat="server"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="TestLabel2" Text ="howdy" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="TestLabel3" Text = "emails" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on your `button` save, Form1_Load is execute first and after your SaveButton function, thats why you have old datas. So you need to put your Form1_Load code in PostBack :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

   if not IsPostBack then
       //your code
   end if

End Sub
```

You can check [this post](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-asp-net/0596001711/ch03s06.html) about postback.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help! When i try to add this to the form1_load an error comes up for the "if(!IsPostBack) then" line because it says "Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' Statement